# How to trace curvy lines in an image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, retina

I'm trying to trace a few curvy lines (vessels) in a retina image. The vessels are very clear in the image, so I thought this would be very straight forward, but I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Here is a link to the actual image:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cRTk37U7LSeaV6rhvg0K6FKYsnDhlQZr

[image]

And I'm looking for the following tracing. Also would like to have that red tracing in a separate file:

[image]

Comment: Try reading about `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach implemented in Imagemagick. You likely can find similar functionality in OpenCV. Not the best detection, but gets most of the lines.

```
Filter noise (20 iterations of -enhance) -- median filtering should work.

Perform local area (adaptive) thresholding (-lat)

Perform morphology thinning

Use connected components processing to remove small isolate regions (<100)

Do morphology dilate to thicken the lines.
```

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.jpg \
-enhance -enhance -enhance -enhance -enhance \
-enhance -enhance -enhance -enhance -enhance \
-enhance -enhance -enhance -enhance -enhance \
-enhance -enhance -enhance -enhance -enhance \
-negate -lat 50x50+1% \
-morphology Thinning:-1 Skeleton \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
-morphology dilate octagon:3 \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. Is this python code?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, it is Imagemagick code.